# insertion sort in python?

Tags: python, sorting

I wrote a code for insertion sort that now works great (yes, it's homework). But, before that code I wrote a different one that doesn't work and I just don't know why. Please help me understand...

This is my older code:

```
def insertion_sort(lst):
    if len(lst)==1:
        lst=lst
    else:
        for i in lst[1:]:
            if i==min(lst[0:lst.index(i)]):
                 lst.remove(i)
                 lst.insert(0, i)
    return lst
```

I do not need a new insertion sort, I already wrote one. I just need the explanation for why this specific code didn't work.

Comment: What is `lst=lst` supposed to do?

Comment: @NiclasNilsson Glorified `pass` statement?

Comment: yes.. i'm new to this, I still write codes in a very stupid way.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that sometimes, even though `i` isn't the smallest of `lst[0:lst.index(i)]`, it still needs to be moved downwards. So, for example, if `lst[0:lst.index(i)]` is `[0, 1, 2, 4, 3]`, then even though the minimum is `0`, you still need to move `3` down a place for insertion sort to work.

Comment: I don't understand, why is that?